# How to check if CheckBoxes are empty in an Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, checkbox

I have a couple of CheckBoxes:

```
    checkBox1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.one);
    checkBox2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.two;
    checkBox3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.three);
    checkBox4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.four);
    checkBox5 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.five);
    checkBox6 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.six);
    checkBox7 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.seven);
```

Then I add them into an array:

```
    List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    CheckBox checkBox;        
    checkBoxes.add(checkBox1); checkBoxes.add(checkBox2);
    checkBoxes.add(checkBox3); checkBoxes.add(checkBox4);
    checkBoxes.add(checkBox5); checkBoxes.add(checkBox6);
    checkBoxes.add(checkBox7);
```

I want to make a Toast if one of the CheckBoxes are empty on a button click. So I use a for loop inside a button:

```
public void onButtonClick(){
        for(int i = 0; i <checkBoxes.size(); i++){
            checkBox = checkBoxes.get(i);
        }
       if(!checkBox.isChecked){
            //make Toast "Hey, you didn't check a box"
      }else{
           //do something based on the checked box.
      }
  }
```

The problem is the Toast is still being shown if a CheckBox is checked and it is not executing the else code.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only gets the last checkbox.  You need to do some more work inside the loop:

```
public void onButtonClick() {
    boolean atLeastOneChecked = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.size(); i++){
        CheckBox checkBox = checkBoxes.get(i);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            atLeastOneChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!atLeastOneChecked){
        //make Toast "Hey, you didn't check a box"
    } else {
        //do something based on the checked box.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer.